# ¿por qué la variable de clase no se actualiza correctamente?

Tags: python, nosql, diseño-de-clases

Tengo el siguiente codigo que me ayuda manejar unos esquemas no relacionales(diccionarios). al crear una instancia de clase, y acceder a los metodos que actualizan la variable de clase db_main, se duplican los valores para la la segunda actualizacion. por que?

La secuencia es esta:

```
  i = NosqlDb()
  i.update_s1('data1','data2')
  i.update_main()
  i.update_s1('data12','data22')
  i.update_main()
  NosqlDB.db_main
```

esto da como resultado:

```
{'for_s1': [{'key1': ['data1', 'data11'], 'key2': ['data2', 'data22']}, 
            {'key1': ['data1', 'data11'], 'key2': ['data2', 'data22']}], 
 'for_s2': ['empty', 'empty'], 
 'for_s3': ['empty', 'empty']}
```

en lugar de:

```
{'for_s1': [{'key1': ['data1'], 'key2': ['data2']}, 
            {'key1': ['data1', 'data11'], 'key2': ['data2', 'data22']}], 
 'for_s2': ['empty', 'empty'], 
 'for_s3': ['empty', 'empty']}
```

el codigo completo es este:

```
class NosqlDb:

    db_main = {'for_s1':[],'for_s2':[],'for_s3':[]}

    def __init__(self):
        self.s1 = {'key1':[],'key2':[]}
        self.s2 = {'field1':[], 'field2':[]}
        self.s3 = {'meta1':[], 'meta2': []}

#methods here
    def update_s1(self, value1,value2):
        self.s1['key1'].append(value1)
        self.s1['key2'].append(value2)

    def update_s2(self, value1,value2):
        self.s2['field1'].append(value1)
        self.s2['field2'].append(value2)

    def update_s3(self, value1,value2):
        self.s3['meta1'].append(value1)
        self.s3['meta2'].append(value2)

    def update_main(self):

        if self.s1['key1'] and self.s1['key2']:
            NosqlDb.db_main['for_s1'].append(self.s1)
        else:
            NosqlDb.db_main['for_s1'].append('empty')

        if self.s2['field1'] and self.s2['field2']:
            NosqlDb.db_main['for_s2'].append(self.s2)
        else:
            NosqlDb.db_main['for_s2'].append('empty')
        if self.s3['meta1'] and self.s3['meta2']:
            NosqlDb.db_main['for_s3'].append(self.s3)
        else:
            NosqlDb.db_main['for_s3'].append('empty')

    def restart_db_main(self):
        NosqlDb.db_main = {'for_s1':[],'for_s2':[],'for_s3':[]}

def main():
    print(NosqlDb.__doc__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Que puede ser?  de antemano gracias!

Comment: En la secuencia, luego de i.update_s1('data12','data22') me faltó: i.update_main(). disculpen, soy nuevo por acá.

Comment: Hola! recuerda que, para añadir info, puedes editar tu pregunta usando el enlace editar que está justo bajo tu pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has intentado seguir el flujo escribiendo en una hoja que guarda cada varible de la clase en cada llamada? Suele ser bastante útil cuando se está empezando (y cuando se tiene unos cuantos años en esto también..)

Vamos allá. Cuando se inicia la clase tienes estos valores:

```
db_main = {'for_s1':[],'for_s2':[],'for_s3':[]}
s1 = {'key1':[],'key2':[]}
s2 = {'field1':[], 'field2':[]}
s3 = {'meta1':[], 'meta2': []}
```

Al hacer esta llamada:

```
i.update_s1('data1','data2')
```

Cambia s1

```
s1 = {'key1':['data1'],'key2':['data2']}
```

Y al hacer el `update_main` nos queda todo así

```
db_main = {'for_s1':[{'key1':['data1'],'key2':['data2']}],'for_s2':[],'for_s3':[]}
s1 = {'key1':['data1'],'key2':['data2']}
s2 = {'field1':[], 'field2':[]}
s3 = {'meta1':[], 'meta2': []}
```

Hasta aquí entiendo que es lo que esperabas y no hay sorpresas.

Entonces al hacer la siguiente llamada: `i.update_s1('data12','data22')` s1 nos queda así:

```
s1 = {'key1':['data1', 'data12'],'key2':['data2', 'data22']}
```

Una vez más, por tu comentario entiendo que es lo que esperas. Pero aquí ha cambiado algo más, incluso antes de llamar a `update_main` y es que `db_main` ahora mismo tiene este valor:

```
db_main = {'for_s1':[{'key1':['data1', 'data12'],'key2':['data2', 'data22']}],'for_s2':[],'for_s3':[]}
```

Y he aquí el problema. Que está pasando?

La respuesta es sencilla cuando entiendes que python referencia los objetos por su posición de memoria. Es decir, cuando has creado `s1` le ha asignado una posición en memoria, digamos `&1`.

En el momento de hacer el append en `db_main['for_s1']` otros lenguajes lo que hacen es hacer una copia de `s1` y asignarle otra posición de memoria, digamos `&2` por lo que `s1` y la lista en  db_main` son diferentes objetos y cuando modificas uno no se modifica el otro.

Pero python no hace eso, sino que lo único que hace es pasar la posición de memoria `&1` y por lo tanto tanto la variable `s1` como `db_main['for_s1']` están apuntando a exactamente el mismo objeto. Por lo cual un cambio en uno afecta el otro.

Dado que no es el comportamiento que esperas, puedes solucionarlo haciendo una copia que tendrá una nueva posición de memoria: `NosqlDb.db_main['for_s1'].append(self.s1.copy())`

Si por lo que fuese no tienes una versión de python 3.3 o mas nueva la forma de conseguir una copia es `self.s1[:]`

La diferencia entre pasar por valor o por posición de memoria se conoce como "pass by value" y "pass by reference" hay algunos lenguajes que incluso te permiten definir si un método debería pasar por valor o referencia, pero no es el caso de python que yo sepa.